how to sort dropdown items in angular checked item first
please how to sort my dropdown list items to make checked items first ?
                    <p-multiSelect
                    [options]="myOptions"
                    [(ngModel)]="option.label"
                    (ngModelChange)="detectChange(option)"
                    [ngClass]="isInheritedFromMain(option.id, relType) ? 'isDisabled' : ''"
                    defaultLabel="Choose an option"
                ></p-multiSelect >



The sortOptions() function makes sure that the options you have in
your dropdown are always sorted so that the selected items (checked
options) appear at the top.
The detectChange() function is called
whenever you select or unselect an option. It runs the sortOptions()
function to reorder the options, ensuring that selected ones stay at
the top after any change.



  myOptions = [
    { label: 'Option 1', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Option 2', value: 2 },
    { label: 'Option 3', value: 3 },
    { label: 'Option 4', value: 4 }
  ];
  selectedOptions: any[] = [];

  detectChange(option: any) {
    this.sortOptions();
  }

  sortOptions() {
    // Sort the options so that checked items are first
    this.myOptions.sort((a, b) => {
      const isASelected = this.selectedOptions.some(item => item.value === a.value);
      const isBSelected = this.selectedOptions.some(item => item.value === b.value);
      if (isASelected && !isBSelected) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (!isASelected && isBSelected) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0; // Keep original order if both are either checked or unchecked
    });
  }



